# what does "to which it is a party" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, expressions, legalese

I have a statement here,  and I dont get the meaning exactly:

> Each of the Members agrees to make an annual report to the International Labour Office on the measures which it has taken to give effect to the provisions of Conventions **to which it is a party**.

Q1. Does *provisions of Conventions* here mean statements in an agreement? ie. *provisions* - statements in legal documents;
*Conventions* - agreement between country leaders

Q2. what does *to which it is a party* at the end of statement mean? does it mean same *as to which it **as** a party*?

Comment: If you're a party to an agreement, then you're one of the people who have signed the agreement or otherwise bound themselves to follow its terms.

Comment: It doesn't mean the same as “to which it as a party”, because that is completely ungrammatical and doesn't mean anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

The Conventions being described are the agreements (essentially treaties) reached through the  International Labour Organization, the 12 most important of which are [listed on its website](http://www.ilo.org/global/standards/introduction-to-international-labour-standards/conventions-and-recommendations/lang--en/index.htm).  Each one involves a series of commitments: for example Article 3 of the [Minimum Age Convention](http://www.ilo.org/dyn/normlex/en/f?p=NORMLEXPUB:12100:0::NO::P12100_ILO_CODE:C138) says the minimum age for work which is likely to jeopardise the health, safety or morals of young persons shall not be less than 18 years.

The parties to a Convention are the countries which have signed it (and ratified it, so it comes into force for them), and have not denounced it: for example [168 countries](http://www.ilo.org/dyn/normlex/en/f?p=1000:11300:0::NO:11300:P11300_INSTRUMENT_ID:312283) have ratified the Minimum Age Convention and a [further 18](http://www.ilo.org/dyn/normlex/en/f?p=NORMLEXPUB:11310:0::NO:11310:P11310_INSTRUMENT_ID:312283:NO) (including the Unites States and Iran) have signed but not ratified.

Your sentence simply says that the countries have to report annually on what they have done in meeting their commitments.

Comment: Thanks heaps Rathony and Henry. This seems like a legal document which i havent seen something alike before.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: You are right. "Provisions of Conventions" means "conditions/statements agreed upon in Conventions".

Q2: "The provisions of Conventions to which it is a party" means "the specific conditions that "a" Member has agreed to abide by". Some conditions might be relevant to "A" party (member), but not to "B" party. That's why it uses "to which it is a party" to specify "A party will abide by the conditions that are relavant to him".

"To which it is a party" is necessary to denote "all conditions don't necessarily apply to all members".

[Party](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/party) in the above means:

> A person or people forming one side in an agreement or dispute:

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I just want to clarify few things. So does it  mean - relevant countries (which it is a party) who agreed on specific conditions(provisions of Conventions) will agree on making annual report to ILO?     What does "on the measures" mean then?

Comment: "All members will make a report on the measures that are related with specific conditions each member agreed to abide by. Note: Not all the conditions apply to all the members.

Comment: sorry to keep on bothering you, so the Conventions doesnt mean an actual agreement, it means a 'meeting' in this context? 2ndly, coming back to which it is a party question, does it mean "specific members(party) who are relevant to the issues"

Comment: Where did I state that conventions don't mean agreements? "to which it is a party" is necessary to denote "all conditions don't apply to all members".